# List svn diffs for all files in specific revison

Tags: bash, svn, command-line

There is a command for listing all files in a certain revision:

```
svn log --summarize -r119977:r119978

   M /tradefed/DeathStarService/trunk/CMakeLists.txt
   M /tradefed/DeathStarService/trunk/build.sh
   ...
```

There is a command for seeing difference for a file in a certain revision:

```
svn diff trunk/build.sh -r119977:r119978
```

Is there a command-line to see differences in all files in a certain revision?

Comment: BTW, shorthand for `-r N-1:N` is `-c N`, `-r N:M` used mostly for non-adjacent revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just omit the file specification from the diff command.

```
svn diff -r119977:r119978
```